# How to pass parameter to the attachEvent Javascript function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have to pass a parameter the `validateNum` Javascript function (e.g. num1, num2)

```
if (num1.attachEvent) {
 num1.attachEvent("onkeypress", validateNum);  
}
```

How to pass? Can I get a code sample?

Comment: Does `validateNum` use the `event` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make an anonymous currier:

```
num1.attachEvent("onkeypress", function() { return validateNum(num1, num2); });
```

Comment: OK but how do I detach the event should I need to if I do this? :)

Comment: @wlf: Store the handler in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from [SLaks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663631/how-to-pass-parameter-to-the-attachevent-javascript-function/2663642#2663642), in ECMAScript 5th Edition implementations you can use the `bind` method:

```
num1.attachEvent("onkeypress", validateNum.bind(null, num1, num2));
```

In implementations that don't support the method you can either use the [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) JS framework or just add the method to the Function prototype with this snippet:

```
if (!('bind' in Function.prototype)) {
    Function.prototype.bind= function(owner) {
        var that= this;
        var args= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return function() {
            return that.apply(owner,
                args.length===0? arguments : arguments.length===0? args :
                args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0))
            );
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Do any real browsers support this?

Comment: @SLaks: tbh I'm not sure, ECMAScript 5th was published in Dec 09.  Even still, it doesn't hurt to add the method for forwards compatibility purposes.

Comment: I'm not aware of any support in released browsers, but it's certainly expected to show up in forthcoming versions (eg. Firefox 3.7).

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly i get solution to pass 'this' as a parameter.
if anyone get here search for this(kkkk)....

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ch_aceito" id="ch-aceito" value="1" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";

    var el = document.getElementById("ch-aceito");

    function isIE () {
      var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
    }

    //alert(isIE());

    if (document.addEventListener) {
        //console.log('here');
        el.addEventListener("click", getPost, false);
    } else {
        el.attachEvent("onclick", function() { 
            getPost(el);
        });  
    }

    function getPost(el){
        if(isIE() && isIE() <= 8){
            alert(el.value);
        } else {
            alert(this.value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I get isIE from here:

[Detect IE version (prior to v9) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-prior-to-v9-in-javascript)